# SerialPort not writing data with long strings - FIXED

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am writing a program which writes `channel urls` and `channel names` to a device. I'm trying to write `channel urls` with a length of 254. Shorter urls (I haven't found the threshold yet) do work. 
What makes it more strange is that the `channel names` are only 16 characters long, and these do also only write when the `channel urls` are shorter.

I have the following code which works:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChannels; i++)
            {
                string hexString = String.Format("{0:X1}", i);
                Serialport.WriteLine("channel 2 " + hexString + " " + channelURLs[i]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Serialport.WriteLine("channel 1 " + hexString + " " + channelnames[i]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

however, I do not want to have my code sleep 2seconds for writing 1 channel. QUESTION: How do I get those long strings written through the serialport without waiting 2 seconds?

This does not work:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChannels; i++)
            {
                string hexString = String.Format("{0:X1}", i);
                if (Serialport.WriteLine("channel 2 " + hexString + " " + channelURLs[i]))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("this should happen before the string is written");
                }
                if(Serialport.WriteLine("channel 1 " + hexString + " " + channelnames[i]))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("this should happen before the string is written");
                }
            }
```

the debug lines are written, and the string is not written through the comport.

my `Serialport.WriteLine` function looks like this:

```
    public static bool WriteLine(string data)
    {
        if (SerPort.IsOpen)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("PORT OPEN, WRITING "+ data);
            SerPort.WriteLine(data);
            return true;
        }
        else return false;

    }
```

UPDATE: I found that when I disconnect and reconnect, the first URL is written. Apparently it has to do with some buffer?

UPDATE2: This is how I set up my serialport:

```
                    SerPort.BaudRate = 115200;
                    SerPort.DataBits = 8;
                    SerPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    SerPort.PortName = comnr;
                    SerPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                    Serialport.SerPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                    Serialport.SerPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
                    SerPort.DataReceived += SerPort_Datareceived;
                    SerPort.Open();
                    SerPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                    SerPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
```

UPDATE 3: Fixed the issue
I've found where my issue was. Before sending the commands shown here, I sent a command which took some time to process. If the device recieved data during this process it would stop receiving data. I updated my code with a timer to check for an OK respond from the device before sending the next commands.

Comment: How do you know they are not being written?  Also, it would be helpful to see the setup for the SerialPort.

Comment: The device responds the bytes it receives, which i monitor. I do not see any of those. Also if I check whether any channel has been added it does not show anything. I'll update the information about the serialport

Comment: Before assuming the data isn't sent, I'd connect the serial cable to a PC and check what's being received with a hyperterminal or equivalent software.

Comment: What specifically is the device you are connecting to?  It does sound like this is a failure of the device.  You can confirm this by taking Marcello's advice.  Strings of this length aren't a problem for the SerialPort.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani I have that, I monitor all data. dbasnett The specific device is custom, not relevant here i think.

Comment: Did you try what @MarcelloRomani suggested?  The device is relevant if it isn't capable of processing these length of strings at this bit rate.  Have you tried a lower bit rate?

Comment: Ok, I assume you mean that the strings are received by the hyperterminal in their entirety. That, and the fact that when you put a 1s delay between one transmission and the next everything works makes me think the problem is related to how fast the receiving device is able to process the data. As @fhelwanger wrote, you could try to progressively decrease the 1000ms delay, and see when the system starts to misbehave.

Comment: @2pietjuh2 Do you have any influence on the device's firmware? I'd say you need to debug there. Maybe there's a buffer overflow? Is the protocol using some kind of end-of-text character?

Comment: @JeffRSon I did not have influence on the device's firmware. but indeed the problem was there. Thanks all:)

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the device you are working on. If you send too many bytes to it, there's a chance that it cannot process them all.

You can try to decrease the waiting time from 1000 ms to, for example, 200 ms.

You can also try to send packages of data... for example, send the long string in packages of 50 characters, waiting an amount of time between them (example, 100 ms).

UPDATE 1:

Also try to decrease the BaudRate from 115200 to 9600.